# AWS SDK 2.0+ jar download

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven

I'm trying to execute the S3 sample program from

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/basics-async.html

The program has below imports

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.async.AsyncResponseTransformer;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3AsyncClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.GetObjectResponse;
```

Want to down the jar which has below imports. MY IDE complains that it was not able to find it
I tried adding below entry in pom.xml and tried `mvn clean install`.

Still facing issue. Any suggestions

**Maven**

```
             <dependency>
                <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.13.7</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
```

Comment: You have tried to find the library in the .m2 folder, as long as you have the libraries down there.

Comment: now i tried for `<groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>sdk-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.49</version>` and the jar is not containing the expected classes

Comment: What classes fail, because I saw an issue on Github from a year ago, I add it here https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/1037

Comment: I have searched a little more and in the repository of the exercise that you are following they use another version of that library. I think that may be the problem https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javav2/example_code/s3/pom.xml